# how does feature selection for random forest help

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest

I came across [this link](http://blog.datadive.net/selecting-good-features-part-iii-random-forests/) which talks about feature selections in random forest

It introduces two methods

- Mean decrease impurity
- Mean decrease accuracy

I would like to know if there are more methods and when should one method be preferred.

Also is it correct to say that less feature for random forest always gives worse result and the only gain is in computation speed?

Comment: I think that, when you have a large number of features w.r.t. a small number of observation you should **always** run a feature selection algorithm before applying any classification method. That is because, the more feature (predictors) you have, the higher is the probability that **by chance** one of these features is correlated with the outcome variable, leading to sub-optimal results. Here (http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/367/1906/4237) for example, it is said that **as a rule of thumb**, the number of features should be no more than one fifth of the number of observations.